# Read and writing a inifile in a Delphi Firemonkey Mobile Application?

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

If this has already been visited here on SO, please point me to it, cause I cant seem to find it. Having said that:

Using the standard delphi application events, as well as the [Mobile app lifecycle events handling](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/pawelglowacki/2013/09/30/40067) , i am trying to find the best spot to read and write a INI file?

as I test, i created a demo app with a button which increments a count variable and displays it in a show message

```
procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 inc(Count);
 ShowMessage(IntToStr(Count));
end;
```

In the main form's OnCreate even, I read the inifile

```
procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
 Ini: TIniFile;
begin
 Ini := TIniFile.Create( TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + 'fortysixtozero.ini' );
 try
  Count    := Ini.ReadInteger( 'Main', 'Count', 0 );
 finally
  Ini.Free;
 end;
end;
```

Now, knowing that a mobile app can have different states, i am wondering where the best place is to write the ini file?

Comment: Why use an ini file on mobile? And aren't you expected to use `TPath.Combine`?

Comment: What do you recommend to store application settings if not ini file? I am not sure why you are asking me the question about TPath.combine? If you are the expert, shouldn't you be telling me if I should or should not be useing it? And why.

Comment: OK then. Don't manually add `PathDelim` to construct a path. Use `TPath.Combine`. For instance `TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'fortysixtozero.ini'). This makes sure that there's no chance of repeated path delimiters and also makes the intent much clearer to the reader of the code.

Comment: I just googled it and found it - System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(System.IOUtils.tpath.getdocumentspath,'test.txt'); - THANKS, but i still doesn't answer my original question of when to do the writing. Also, why not ini file. What do you recommend?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Best states to save the application state or store settings is "**aeEnteredBackground**". I used the delphi FMX event here. You should also check the "**aeWillBecomeInactive**" and "**aeWillTerminate**" events, but the first one is the most relavant. The application enters background when another application is opened or yours is closed (they are not terminated right away).

Check this [article](http://www.fmxexpress.com/handle-android-and-ios-lifecycle-events-in-delphi-xe5-firemonkey/).

The code to listen for events looks like this:

```
function TfMain.HandleAppEvent(AAppEvent: TApplicationEvent; AContext: TObject): Boolean; 
begin  
  case AAppEvent of
    aeFinishedLaunching: ;
    aeBecameActive: ;
    aeWillBecomeInactive: ;
    aeEnteredBackground: ;
    aeWillBecomeForeground: ;
    aeWillTerminate: ;
    aeLowMemory: ;
    aeTimeChange: ;
    aeOpenURL: ;   
  end;

  Result := True; 
end;
```

To attach the listener you use the platform services:

```
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXApplicationEventService, IInterface(SvcEvents)) then
    SvcEvents.SetApplicationEventHandler(HandleAppEvent);
```

Just add "FMX.Platform" to your uses clause.

Answer (score 5):

In Delphi XE7, there is an "OnSaveState" event for forms.  This is the preferred place to save application data since it will execute when an iOS app goes into the "background" state.  The documentation is quite helpful... search for "save state".

Here is my code in the main form's OnCreate handler:

```
procedure TMainWindow.FormCreate( Sender : TObject );

var
   IniFile : TIniFile;

   Metric : BOOLEAN;

   IniFileName : STRING;

   Reader : TBinaryReader;

begin
   fInitializing := True;

   SaveState.StoragePath := TPath.GetLibraryPath;

   if SaveState.Stream.Size > 0 then begin
      Reader := TBinaryReader.Create( SaveState.Stream );

      try
         Metric := Reader.ReadBoolean;

         vMetricUnits.IsChecked := Metric;

         SetSliderLimits( Metric );

         Temperature := Reader.ReadDouble;

         Dewpoint := Reader.ReadDouble;

         Humidity := Reader.ReadDouble;

         WindSpeed := Reader.ReadDouble;

      finally
         Reader.Free;
      end;
   end

   else begin
      Metric := False;

      vMetricUnits.IsChecked := Metric;

      SetSliderLimits( Metric );

      Temperature := 70;

      Dewpoint := 70;

      Humidity := 100;

      WindSpeed := 0;
   end;

   SetMetricUnits( cMetricUnits );

   fInitializing := False;

   WriteTrackbarCaptions;

   CalculateTemperatures;
end;
```

And here is the code in the form's OnSaveState handler:

```
procedure TMainWindow.FormSaveState( Sender : TObject );

var
   Writer : TBinaryWriter;

begin
   SaveState.Stream.Clear;

   Writer := TBinaryWriter.Create( SaveState.Stream );

   try
      Writer.Write( cMetricUnits );

      Writer.Write( Temperature );

      Writer.Write( Dewpoint );

      Writer.Write( Humidity );

      Writer.Write( WindSpeed );

   finally
      Writer.Free;
   end;
end;
```

I've tested this on both the iPad and in Windows and it works on both platforms.  Doing it this way completely avoids the use of the .ini file, however it does create a somewhat oddly named .tmp file in the Windows version.  I assume that an equivalent file is also created on the iPad.